# Convert Feet to meters in excel with macro for entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I am no programmer I am an avionics tech trying to manipulate data from our jets. One I have made a macro that eliminates all unnecessary columns, and adds columns and values to it so that it displays as a kml correctly. However, I cannot find a way to convert feet to meters in the macro for thousands of cells.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()
Sheets("GRT Flight Data    Log_raw").Range("A:B,H:I,K:L,P:P,AB:AH,AK:AN,AQ:AQ,AT:AT,AZ:BJ").EntireColumn.Delete

Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("G1").Value = "AppendDataColumnsToDescription"

Range("G2:G363").Value = "Yes"

Range("F1").Value = "IconAltitude"

Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("H1").Value = "IconAltitudeMode"

Range("H2:H363").Value = "MSL"

Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("I1").Value = "Icon"

Range("I2:I363").Value = "222"

Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("J1").Value = "IconHeading"

Range("J2:J363").Value = "line-0"

Columns("K:K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("K1").Value = "IconScale"

Range("K2:K363").Value = ".5"

Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("L1").Value = "IconLineColor"

Range("L2:L363").Value = "Cyan"

Columns("M:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("M1").Value = "LineStringColor"

Range("M2:M363").Value = "Lime"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert Feet to Kilometers using the **CONVERT** function:

> =CONVERT(A2,"ft","km")

[image]

In VBA you can call it as a worksheet function:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(.Value, "ft", "km")
```

In order to include this in your code, add the following lines to your code:

```
Dim lastrow as long

lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For x=2 to lastrow
    Cells(x,6).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(Cells(x,6).value, "ft", "km")
Next x
```

This is how I would change your code, if you want row 363 to be your last row. Note that xLng can be updated to any number if the last row needs to be something other than 363:

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()

Dim xLng As Long

xLng = 363

Sheets("GRT Flight Data    Log_raw").Range("A:B,H:I,K:L,P:P,AB:AH,AK:AN,AQ:AQ,AT:AT,AZ:BJ").EntireColumn.Delete

Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("G1").Value = "AppendDataColumnsToDescription"
Range("G2:G" & xLng).Value = "Yes"

Range("F1").Value = "IconAltitude"
For x = 2 To xLng
    Cells(x, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(Cells(x, 6).Value, "ft", "km")
Next x

Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("H1").Value = "IconAltitudeMode"
Range("H2:H" & xLng).Value = "MSL"

Columns("I:I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("I1").Value = "Icon"
Range("I2:I" & xLng).Value = "222"

Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("J1").Value = "IconHeading"
Range("J2:J" & xLng).Value = "line-0"

Columns("K:K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("K1").Value = "IconScale"
Range("K2:K" & xLng).Value = ".5"

Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("L1").Value = "IconLineColor"
Range("L2:L" & xLng).Value = "Cyan"

Columns("M:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("M1").Value = "LineStringColor"
Range("M2:M" & xLng).Value = "Lime"

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try the vba function i get requires =

Comment: Can you please edit your question and share your code? It is difficult for me to understand an error without seeing the code.

Comment: @ChristopherRogers you will need to iterate through the cells you want to convert and then you would set the cell value equal to the above equation change `.value` to the cell.

Comment: I added the rest of the code that I am using, I am trying to keep it as simple as possible as this has to be "new guy" proof. I am trying to add the ft to m range F2 through Fxxxx.

Comment: @ChristopherRogers You need to include a loop in order to convert the values in the range. I have added the piece of code you are missing.

Comment: There has to be a way for me to add it with a simple convert(f2:f363,"ft", "m") I really do not want a loop running on 250,000 cells that would take forever.

Comment: No you can't, because each value needs to be assessed and converted individually. Do you have 250,000 cells with values in column F? lastrow is dynamic and will first check for the row with the last value before starting the loop.

Comment: Yes it is a flight log in some instances it records at 5hz (5 x a sec). Over a 2 or 3 hr flight or after multiple files it is not uncommon for there to be 250k + rows of data that goes all the way out to BJ. It will take forever for it to go through all those cells with a loop.

Comment: I see, so why do you want it only to go to row 363?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to stop the loop at row 363? Otherwise you could do something like Range("BK2:BK363").Formula = "=CONVERT(F2,""ft"",""km"")", but this will not update the value in column F, but rather show the converted value in column BK.

Comment: Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim v As Variant
Set r1 = Columns("E:E")
Set r2 = Columns("I:I")
v = r1.Value
r1.Value = r2.Value
r2.Value = v

Comment: So,  we are close I think. The column being recalculated is the altitude that field changes constantly as time goes on. The f363 is based on a simulator flight of 5 mins, that will change per flight, which I am OK changing manually each time for the whole macro. The code you wrote looks good but only looks like it is recalculating f2, is this correct? I can provide sample data with my macro if you can help me figure this out. BTW the data is for a fleet of bd5j jets. This macro simplifies the data and prepared it for kml conversion. Which then plots path and altitude on Google Earth.

Comment: Are you referring to Range("BK2:BK363").Formula = "=CONVERT(F2,""ft"",""km"")"? If so, F2 should change its value with each cell.  Alternatively, you can also change lastrow in in the loop to 363.

Comment: Added your code with the loop that only goes to xLng, which is set as row 363. If you change xLng, all ranges in your code will change to that number.

Comment: You have to have the Analysis toolbox loaded as an Excel plugin.

Comment: @ja72 In order to do what?

Comment: You my friend are awesome, The coding change worked flawlessly ran it on 12207 lines with just a change to the one field and this was the resulting KML from your change in the coding. https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvSQg0Gfln-8gZ1RurwE1RS6ie20qw

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help with your code. Don't forget to tick the "accept answer" box if you liked my answer.

Comment: @VBAPete To use `CONVERT()` function. At least for Excel 2003 it was a requirement. They might have moved the function into the built-in libraries in later versions.

Comment: @ja72 Not sure about Excel 2003, but in Excel 2010 it is a standard function.

Answer (score 0):

To take all values from a column, convert them and write the results in a different column follow the example below

```
Sub ConvertFtToMetersExample(ByRef r_in as Range, ByRef r_out as Range)

    Dim nr as long, i as Long
    'Count the rows on the input range
    nr = r_in.Rows.Count
    'Set output range to be the same size as the input range
    Set r_out = r_out.Resize(nr,1)
    'Set temporary array storage in memory
    Dim values() as Variant
    'Read all values in one swoop
    values = r_in.Value2
    'Go through all of the and transform them.
    'This is a fast operation as it is done in memory and away from the GUI
    For i=1 to nr
        values(i,1) = (12#*0.0254)*values(i,1)
    Next i
    'Export out all the values to the r_out range
    r_out.Value2 = values

Exit Sub
```

**Edit 1**

You can also use the `CONVERT()` worksheet function

```
values(i,1) = WorksheetFunctions.Convert(values(i,1), "ft", "m")
```

Comment: The hard coded conversion is based on `(12 inches/ft)` and `(0.0254 meters/inch)`.